# How can I create new identities with sums?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction, fibonacci-numbers

**1.** There are a lot of ``simple'' identities like
$$
1+\dotsb+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
or
$$
1^2+\dotsb+n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$
**2.** Some include Fibonacci numbers, like in [Prove Fibonacci Identity using generating functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060740/prove-fibonacci-identity-using-generating-functions) or [Help to prove $F_n^5+F_{n+1}^5=F_{n+2}[(F_nF_{n+1}+F_{n-1}^2)^2+F_{n-1}^2F_nF_{n+1}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065916/help-to-prove-f-n5f-n15-f-n2f-nf-n1f-n-122f-n-12f-nf-n) .

**3.** There are also some combinatorical identities, e. g. [Show that ${n\choose r}2^r 3^{n-r}=\sum_{k=r}^{n} {n \choose k} {k \choose r}2^k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667165/show-that-n-choose-r2r-3n-r-sum-k-rn-n-choose-k-k-choose-r2k?rq=1)

Identities of the first type can be generated by solving coefficients, e. g.
$$
1^7 + 4^7 + \dotsb + (3n+1)^7
$$
should probably be a polynomial of 8th degree.

I am interested if there is any way of generating identities of the second or the third type.

Comment: For $1^7+4^7+...$ there is very ugly, but smooth enough way.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg can also be done via summation by parts, I guess

Comment: I have a solution by the telescopic sum.

Comment: Are you familiar with induction?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor yes, of course. I have finished the university course in mathematics

Comment: $\frac{1}{8} (n+1) (3 n+2) \left(729 n^6+3645 n^5+5913 n^4+2835 n^3-288 n^2+270
   n+4\right)$ is not bad. Moreover, we could reduce that to the product of twocubics I bet

Comment: See also the book ["A=B"](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third type:

For most usual sums whose terms contain binomial coefficients (including your example), the combination of Zeilberger and Petkovsek algorithms will check whether there is a closed form.

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeilbergersAlgorithm.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petkov%C5%A1ek%27s_algorithm for more information and references.